# list the values instead of the formatted values with proc sql select into

Tags: sas, proc-sql

When doing a proc sql select into, I get the list of formatted values.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select germ
    into :oklist separated by '","'
    from maxposition
    where max <=10
    ;run;quit;
%put oklist=("&oklist");
```

> oklist=("B. pertussis","Campylobacter","C. trachomatis","E. coli (VTEC)","Giardia","L. 
>   pneumophila","Salmonella","Hepatitis A virus","Hepatitis B virus","Hepatitis C virus","Influenza 
>   virus","Mumps virus")

How can you list the unformatted values instead?

(I mean without changing or removing the format)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `format=` statement in the `proc sql` to assign a generic format.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select germ format=$20.
    into :oklist separated by '","'
    from maxposition
    where max <=10
    ;run;quit;
%put oklist=("&oklist");
```